# Entry IsPassword and IsReadOnly

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I want to create a DetailsPage that shows non-editable information where some values are hidden/masked like a password entry with "*****".  I would like the user to be able to toggle a button that allows them to see the value.  I tried using an Entry control that has a binding to IsPassword with IsReadOnly set to true as follows:

```
<HorizontalStackLayout>
    <Entry Text="{Binding SomeValue}" 
            IsPassword="{Binding ShowValue}" 
            IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <ImageButton Source="visibility.svg"
                    Padding="20,0,0,0"
                    Command="{Binding ToggleValueCommand}"/>
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

However, when IsReadOnly is set to true the entry shows the text value even when IsPassword is True

Is this the proper behavior?
If I cannot use an Entry with IsReadOnly="True", then what is the best way to have a Label have this functionality.  Should I use a ValueConverter or a Behavior?

Comment: Didn't test the issue, but how about binding text to this ```MaskValue => new string('*', SomeValue?.Count);```

Comment: I can't tell it's by design or a potential issue , but you can use a Label as workaround , see answer below.

Comment: I have the same issue but only on Android (iOS works as expected) so probably some MAUI bug. Not sure if there is a ticket for that on their GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround , you can replace `Entry` with a `Label` , change the value while clicking the button each time .

#### Sample code

###### Xaml

```java
<HorizontalStackLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding SomeValue}" />
    <ImageButton Source="visibility.svg" Padding="20,0,0,0" Command="{Binding ToggleValueCommand}"/>
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

###### code behind

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool showValue;

    private string someValue;
    public string SomeValue
    {
        get
        {
            return someValue;
        }
        set
        {
            someValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand ToggleValueCommand { get; set; }

    private string copy;
 
    public ViewModel()
    {
        showValue = true;
        SomeValue = "1234";
        copy = SomeValue;

        ToggleValueCommand = new Command<string>((s) => {

            showValue = !showValue;

            if (showValue)
            {
                SomeValue = copy;
            }
            else
            {
                SomeValue = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < copy.Length; i++)
                {
                    SomeValue += "*";
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```